# Merging partitions, and preserving the data

Tags: command-line, partitioning, lvm

I've got an old server that will be re-purposed. Part of this means rearranging the partitions. The current layout is:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                       8:0    0 558.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1                    8:1    0 243.5M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                    8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5                    8:5    0 558.5G  0 part 
  ├─root                254:0    0   9.3G  0 lvm  /
  ├─swap_1              254:1    0  21.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─home                254:2    0 527.4G  0 lvm  /opt
sr0                      11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The root partition is very small, and I need to merge it with home to make one single partition. Is it possible to merge these without losing data? I'm concerned that if data is lost in either partition, I might not be able to log in again - I *only* have ssh access. The machine is in a data centre that I can't get physical access to should something go wrong. I can't just pop in a Live CD and repartition from there.

---

I know there are many GUI tools that can manage partitions, I need a CLI solution.

Comment: I think what you want is safe and easy with LVMs, but I am not sure so let's wait for someone who knows LVMs better. In the mean time, do you _need_ to merge? Why not make `/usr` a symlink pointing to `/home/usr` for example?

Comment: @terdon: The server is already a bit of a mess with symlinks doing things like that (and some are broken...), and I suspect it's been like that for quite a while. I think (hope?) that merging the partitions will be a good first step in the clean-up that is to follow. At one point I thought about reinstalling the OS from scratch but that would probably take longer than I have.

Comment: Can you take the system off-line?  then booting from a USB and simply copying things over and changing the boot flags would be easiest.

Comment: @Fabby: I don't have physical access to this machine so that would probably be difficult. Getting someone else to do it would probably take too long (mostly because the people with access are busy and I would expect a certain minimum amount of red tape for that kind of request).

Comment: Move / to /home using [pivot_root](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pivot_root), update fstab, delete the / after it successfully reboots an option then?  Do you have a KVM console into the thing? or limited to ssh?

Comment: @Fabby: Access is _only_ via ssh. I've never head of pivot_root so thanks for pointing it out, I'll have a look.

Comment: @Fabby: Some quick reading of pivot_root suggets it only changes the root directory for the current process. I'm not sure how I can use that to permanently change it. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You're concerned about it not booting if data is lost in either partition... but data in `/home` isn't normally required to boot. It's normally the personal files/settings/etc. of individual users on the machine. How much space is actually used in each partition? If possible, it's *much* easier to merge /home to / than the other way around!

Comment: (actually, I see it's called home but mounted under `/opt` — also not normally needed to boot. Is there any data there?)

Comment: @derobert: `/home` is actually a symlink to `/opt/home`. Because I only have ssh access, I'm worried that if I lose *my* home directory, I might not be able to log in anymore. Is that fear realistic?? I honestly am not sure. I'm not too picky about which partition gets merged into which, I just need to do this in such a way that I can still log in over the network and continue working afterwards.

Comment: As long as you have free space on `/opt` (the bigger partition; check with `df /opt`) then this can be done safely. Writing an answer.

Comment: @derobert: the "/opt" partition has enough space to store everything from the root partition. I'm just not sure the best way to do it as I've never attempted something like this before (if you have detailed steps to post as an Answer, I'd love to see it!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presuming you actually have free space on `/opt`, and it's a filesystem that supports at least offline shrinking, the safest bet would be:

1. Since your home directory is on `/opt`, you can't be logged in to it — or you won't be able to unmount `/opt`. One way around this is to enable root login via ssh, using public keys. I don't have an Ubuntu box in front of me to be 100% sure of the steps, but it should just be editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to change `PermitRootLogin` to `prohibit-password` (or `without-password`, for older versions of OpenSSH). Then put your public key in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. An alternative (suggested by @bistoco) is to create a new user, with a home directory on the root filesystem, e.g.,: `sudo mkdir /tmphome && sudo adduser --home /tmphome tmpuser && sudo adduser tmpuser sudo`
2. Make sure you can log in as root or the new user now. Do this from another terminal, do not log out your other session until you've logged in as root, either directly or via sudo from the new user (essential for recovery if, e.g., you accidentally broke sshd)
3. Log in a second root session, just in case. You use this if you somehow break your first one.
4. Finally log out your user session, and any others you have.
5. Unmount `/opt`. If `umount /opt` gives an in use error, use `fuser -vm /opt` (or whatever) to see what is accessing it. You might also need to stop some services, or find another session to log out. (If you can't get /opt to unmount, go to step 10 to abort the process).
6. Shrinking a volume often requires an fsck, and its a good idea anyway. You'll probably need to add `-f` to force fsck on a clean device. E.g., `fsck -f /dev/mapper/VGNAME-home`. This may take a while. (If fsck fails, stop. Check for typos. If it's really failing, something is wrong.)
7. Reduce the volume: `lvreduce -Ay -r -L 100G VGNAME/home`. The `-r` tells it to reduce the filesystem *first*. The `100G` is the new size; pick whatever you'd like (of course can't be smaller than the amount of data on `/opt`). This make take a long while, depending on how much data is on the volume. If this fails due to not supported, this isn't going to work. Proceed to 9 to abort. (If it fails complaining you asked it to shrink to much, pick a larger size and repeat the command).
8. Enlarge the rootfs: `lvextend -Ay -r -L 200G VGNAME/root`. Again the `200G` is the size, and can be whatever you need (up to all available space). The `-r` tells it to resize the filesystem as well (after enlarging the LV); typically this can be done on-line. If it can't... well, your system will still be accessible, but really you need to find a way to use a live CD.
9. Regardless of if that worked, `mount /opt`.
10. Make sure you can log in as your user again. Do not log out your root sessions until you've confirmed you can. If you're using SSH connection multiplexing, use `ssh -o ControlPath=none user@host` to make sure a cached connection is not fooling you.
11. Start any services that you had to stop to unmount `/opt`. At least if you want them running.
12. Change the ssh setting back to not allowing root login, if that's the option you pick and is the way it was before. Make sure you can log in a new session before logging out. Always do this when changing sshd config. Or, if you created a new user, remove it with e.g., `deluser --remove-home tmpuser`

PS: You do not need to grow `/` to occupy all the available space. You can always extend it again if you need to — it's often better to leave some space in a PV unallocated.

Comment: Will step 8 work with `/` mounted? i think not.

Comment: @bistoco With most filesystems in current use, yes. You can enlarge them while mounted. ext4 supports it, for example. So do more recent ext3. And XFS, and btrfs, and...

Comment: I think it will be easier on point 1, to create a user with a custom home-folder path under `VGNAME/root` like `sudo mkdir -p /tmphome/ && sudo useradd -m -d /tmphome/ USERNAME`, and give it sudo access. Then login and follow the rest of the steps. No other config changes required.

Comment: @bistoco that's a good idea.

Comment: So, in steps 7 and 8 I resize the two partitions. So it will result in the "/opt" partition being "tightly-fitted" (partition size being as small as possible to accommodate the data on it) and the root partition will be enlarged. I guess I then start moving content from the "/opt" partition to the root partition until the root partition is full and then repeat 7 and 8 - resizing them as necessary? Until "/opt" is mostly empty?

Comment: This seems like it could work. Thanks for the help! I'll be trying this out today or tomorrow. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner yes, you can do that. I'd always leave a little bit of space free on the root partition - completely full might break.

Comment: Ok, so unmount `/opt` fails because the target is busy. fuser output is: ```$ sudo fuser -vm /opt
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/opt:                root     kernel mount /opt
                     messagebus    629 ...e. dbus-daemon
                     root      61638 ...e. sudo
```
Not sure how to get around this. `dbus-daemon` looks important, doesn't look like something that should be killed...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner That dbus-daemon might be a user-session dbus, which will exit when that user logs out (or can just be killed — killing the system one is more dangerous). I see a sudo in there, did you log out your normal user account?

Comment: @derobert: Ah, no I think I left the original user logged in. Maybe that's it...

Comment: Ugh... it turns out that `/usr/bin` was a symlink to `/opt/usr/bin`... so guess what happened when `/opt` was unmounted? *sigh*

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner as long as you're still logged in, you ought to be able to mount it again. (And aren't the lvm commands in /sbin on Ubuntu?) Someone has sure left you a lot of traps, though!

Comment: Nope. Apparently, only root can mount `/opt`. Yes, the lvm commands are in `/sbin`, but I'm not sure I can resize without sudo. I also can't reboot...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I'm confused — how did you unmount it? You need root to do that. Use the same root session to re-mount it (that's one of the reasons to have not one, but two root sessions open.)

Comment: @derobert: yeah... I may have closed one and accidentally forgotten to re-connect when I finished a different task. Kinda embarrassing. :( I think someone else here has the actual root password, so they might be able to correct this. Worst case scenario, I can ask someone to do a hard-reset in the data centre, and then start again, but fixing /usr/bin before moving on.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner ah, yeah, that sucks. Thankfully a reset will fix it.

Comment: @derobert: This process worked. The only catch was crucial files that were on the other partition I was trying to shrink. There's probably a way to see what file is on which partition - I just wish I'd considered it first!

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Glad to hear it worked. There really ought to be an automatic way to find "interesting" relocations like you ran in to — finding cross-device symlinks ought to do it. But I don't know of a tool that does that, might be worth a question. I'm mostly on [unix.se] (where I'm pretty sure that question would be happily accepted), I imagine here is OK too but am less familiar with [ubuntu.se].